# GridSearchCv issue

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, logistic-regression, grid-search

I'm running GridSearchCV from sklearn using the f1_score as the scoring metric for a logistic regression algorithm. Possible parameter values for C being [0.001, 0.01, 0.1, 1.0, 10.0, 100.0]. When I print the best_estimators method I get 0.001 as the best value but I am 100% sure (because I've evaluated it on this value) that the value 1.0 performs better (gets a higher f1_score on the test and training set). Why is this happening?

Comment: It would be really helpful for folks if you showed your code and the output.

Comment: Do you use cross validation in your `GridSearchCV` ? If yes so it is normal. Otherwise it should be what you are saying. If you don't understand why I can write an answer to you ...